# Add a unit test project to an existing Qt Creator project

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I have an existing Qt Creator project which is not a Subdirs project. I have now reached a point where I want to add a unit test project to it. When I create the new unit test project, the "Add as a subproject to..." combo is disabled.

How can I do it? I'm thinking about creating a brand new Subdirs project and adding my existing project to it, and then adding the unit test project as well.

Is that how it should be done or is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah, you need to add an upper level project, which includes your current project as subdir project. This is probably done most easily from command line, I don't think Qt Creator has a helper for this (unless it's been added in a very recent version). You can use Qt Creator to create a subdir project for you, and then maybe add dummy app and test projects under it. Once you see how that works, then do it for your real project by hand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a problem to change the project type to a subdir project (even for a gui app). That's the only way to add a unit test sub project to it.
Steps:

1. As mentioned, make your project a subdir project:

   TEMPLATE = subdirs

   SUBDIRS = gui logic
2. Select File > New file or project ... > Other Project > Qt Unit Test
3. At the last page "summary" of the wizard, select your project for "Add as a subproject to project"
4. Your .pro file will be updated as follows:

   SUBDIRS = gui logic tests

**Note**: If you're manually restructuring the project hierarchy, make sure the name of the sub directory matches the name of .pro file within that sub directory.

For example:

- sub directory name = **test** --> pro file name = **test.pro**
- sub directory name = **src**  --> pro file name = **src.pro**

Comment: In addition to this answer: Here is a github project, using the unit test, where the final project structure shows how it shall look like https://github.com/bruceoutdoors/DrawingApp . A more detailed information may be found here: https://bruceoutdoors.wordpress.com/2015/05/30/project-structure-for-projects-in-qt-creator-with-unit-tests/amp/

Answer (score 0):

No I think you do need to create a subdir project. You can go to [Qt - Adding Subprojects to Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html#adding-subprojects-to-projects) and read the second paragraph.

Comment: actually first the third: "To create a root project, select File > New File or Project > Other Project > Subdirs Project > Choose", then the second paragraph to add the existing project as a subproject, then add the test project to the root subdirs project too

Comment: Indeed that sounds more complete put that way.